# What is required to get a custom module to appear in uninstall list?

Tags: 7

**Solution**: Ayesh K provides the correct answer below.

---

What is required to get a custom module to appear in uninstall list?  I thought all you had to do was specify a database schema in `hook_schema()`, but I've done so and my module does not appear in the uninstall list.  Currently my module consists of the following code in the `.install` file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Table schema definition for the Events Sponsors module.
 */
function event_sponsors_schema() {
    $schema['event_sponsors_sponsors'] = array(
        'description' => 'A collection of event sponsors.',
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'description' => "Unique ID for the sponsor.",
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => '255',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The name of the sponsor.',
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
        'unique keys' => array(
            'id' => array('id'),
        ),
    );

    $schema['event_sponsors_sponsor_relations'] = array(
        'description' => 'Maintains sponsor and node relations.',
        'fields' => array(
            'sid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The sponsor ID, as can be found in the sponsors table.',
            ),
            'nid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The node ID as can be found in the node table.',
            ),
            'ordinal' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'The order this sponsor appears alongside the node.',
            ),
        ),
        'primary keys' => array('sid','nid'),
        'unique keys' => array(
            'sid' => array('sid'),
            'nid' => array('nid'),
        ),
    );

    return $schema;
}
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK after you disable the module, it will apear in uninstall list

Comment: You just need to install the module (if not done already) and disable it; it will appear in the uninstall list (even if it doesn't have a `.install` file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Drupal 6, you needed to install/uninstall schema using `hook_install` and `hook_uninstall`.

This is not necessary for Drupal 7.

Module will appear in uninstall list if both of these conditions are met:

- module implements `hook_schema` OR `hook_uninstall` in its `.install` file.
- module was enabled once and now is in disabled status.

If the only purpose of `hook_uninstall` is to uninstall the schema, you do not need a `hook_uninstall` function. For `variable_del()`, etc: you need. 
If you have any of these and module has data in the site already, you will see the uninstall check box.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_uninstall()` like this way.
variables must not undefined.

```
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  variable_del('mymodule_var');
  variable_del('mymodule_var2');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution for newbies like me in drupal 7.

You can't uninstall a module when it's running or active. So try, to disable your module first and it should appear to uninstall list afterwards.